# Mutate columns such that basenames line up together

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, purrr, tibble

Suppose I have a vector of filepaths that I have split by `"/"` and have put into a dataframe. These file paths have varying lengths, but at the end of the day, I want all the basenames to line up in the same column. I have included below an example of what I mean and a desired output.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tibble(
    V1 = rep("run1", 5),
    V2 = rep("ox", 5),
    V3 = c("performance.csv", "analysis", "analysis", "performance.csv", "analysis"),
    V4 = c("", "rod1", "rod2", "rod3", "performance.csv"), 
    V5 = c("", "performance.csv", "performance.csv", "performance.csv", "")
)

dat
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   V1    V2    V3              V4              V5             
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>           <chr>           <chr>          
#> 1 run1  ox    performance.csv ""              ""             
#> 2 run1  ox    analysis        rod1            performance.csv
#> 3 run1  ox    analysis        rod2            performance.csv
#> 4 run1  ox    performance.csv rod3            performance.csv
#> 5 run1  ox    analysis        performance.csv ""

output <- tibble(
    V1 = rep("run1", 5),
    V2 = rep("ox", 5),
    V3 = c("", "analysis", "analysis", "", "analysis"),
    V4 = c("", "rod1", "rod1", "rod2", ""), 
    V5 = c("performance.csv", "performance.csv", "performance.csv", "performance.csv", "performance.csv")
)

output
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   V1    V2    V3       V4    V5             
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr>          
#> 1 run1  ox    ""       ""    performance.csv
#> 2 run1  ox    analysis rod1  performance.csv
#> 3 run1  ox    analysis rod1  performance.csv
#> 4 run1  ox    ""       rod2  performance.csv
#> 5 run1  ox    analysis ""    performance.csv
```

My thought is to resort to a for-loop in which I check if a column contains a basename and if so, replace it with `""` and move it to the last column. I am having trouble forming this logic and know there must be a better way leveraging tidyverse.

Comment: What assumptions are you making about which column a value goes into?  Are each of the values either the same for all rows or differ by just a numeric suffix? It would be help to be much more clear about how the transformation needs to happen to work with your particular data. This seems like a very unusual operation so I'm not sure there's going to be some easy way to do that.

Comment: @MrFlick, my reprex is a gross over-simplification of the file paths I'm working with. They vary in length greatly with vastly different parent directories. I need to split because I have another list of file paths that I want to associate with this list. My problem is that many of the base files have the same name so I need a way to `left_join()` with unique identifiers for each filepath. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a function `rearrange` that rearranges a row putting the base name at the end blanking out its original position if it is not already at the end.  We assume that any entry with a dot is a base name.  Then apply `rearrange` to each row.

```
rearrange <- function(x) {
  i <- grep(".", x, fixed = TRUE)[1]
  x[length(x)] <- x[i]
  if (i < length(x)) x[i] <- ""
  x
}
as_tibble(t(apply(dat, 1, rearrange)))
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  V1    V2    V3       V4    V5             
  <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr>          
1 run1  ox    ""       ""    performance.csv
2 run1  ox    analysis rod1  performance.csv
3 run1  ox    analysis rod2  performance.csv
4 run1  ox    ""       rod3  performance.csv
5 run1  ox    analysis ""    performance.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `tidyverse` way -

```
dat %>% 
  rownames_to_column("id") %>% 
  gather(key, variable, -id) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(
    variable = case_when(
      key == "V5" ~ tail(grep(".csv", x = variable, value = T), 1),
      key != "V5" & grepl(".csv", x = variable) ~ "",
      TRUE ~ variable
    )
  ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  spread(key, variable)


# A tibble: 5 x 6
  id    V1    V2    V3       V4    V5             
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr>          
1 1     run1  ox    ""       ""    performance.csv
2 2     run1  ox    analysis rod1  performance.csv
3 3     run1  ox    analysis rod2  performance.csv
4 4     run1  ox    ""       rod3  performance.csv
5 5     run1  ox    analysis ""    performance.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `base R` using `max.col`.  Get the column index of subset of dataset (3rd to 5th column) where there is `.` as element, `cbind` with the row index (`seq_len(nrow(dat))`), extract the elements from the dataset based on these index and assign it to 'V5'.  Then change the 3rd and 4th column based on the TRUE values of the logical matrix (`do.call(cbind, .`) to blank (`""`)

```
dat <- as.data.frame(dat)
lst1 <- lapply(dat[3:5], grepl, pattern = '\\.')
ij <- cbind(seq_len(nrow(dat)), max.col(do.call(cbind, lst1), 'first'))
dat$V5 <-  dat[3:5][ij]
dat[3:4][do.call(cbind, lst1[1:2])] <- ""
dat
#    V1 V2       V3   V4              V5
#1 run1 ox               performance.csv
#2 run1 ox analysis rod1 performance.csv
#3 run1 ox analysis rod2 performance.csv
#4 run1 ox          rod3 performance.csv
#5 run1 ox analysis      performance.csv
```

---

Or using `tidyverse` with `coalesce`.  Here, we `select` columns 'V3' to 'V5', loop through the columns (`map`), `replace` the elements that are not `.csv` with `NA`, `coalesce` it to a single column, bind that column with the subset columns of the original dataset and `replace` the 3rd to 4th columns that have the `.` to blank (`""`)

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>% 
  select(V3:V5) %>% 
  map_df(~ replace(.x, str_detect(.x, "\\.csv", negate = TRUE), NA)) %>% 
  transmute(V5 = coalesce(!!! .)) %>%
  bind_cols(dat %>% 
             select(-V5), .) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(3:4), list(~ replace(., str_detect(., "\\."), '')))
# A tibble: 5 x 5
#  V1    V2    V3       V4    V5             
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr>          
#1 run1  ox    ""       ""    performance.csv
#2 run1  ox    analysis rod1  performance.csv
#3 run1  ox    analysis rod2  performance.csv
#4 run1  ox    ""       rod3  performance.csv
#5 run1  ox    analysis ""    performance.csv
```